# Grails findAll slow when a large resultset is returned

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, grails, groovy

I'm trying to use the `.findAll` method on a mapped domain object in Grails. Everything works fine. However, when expecting a result from MySQL, containing a lot of rows (10.000+), it takes a couple of seconds to finish. With 150.000 rows, this took over 30 seconds to finish.

My code:

```
def temperatures = Temperature.findAll(sort: "logDate", order: "desc", max: limit, offset: offset) {
            sighting.device == device
            if (tripId) {
                tripDevice.trip.id == tripId
            }
        }
```

The Temperature has two nested childs.

the `def temperature` is basically a `List` of type `Temperature`. The query itself can be executed in Grails in native SQL in just 0.2 seconds, resulting in thousands of rows. I also tried to use the `lazy` tag for variables I'm not interested in.

I suspect the issue to be the fact that every row is being mapped as an object of `Temperature` (Hibernate), and possibly also the nested objects. This could be well over 100.000 `Temperatures` in a `List`.

I'm trying to find a way to do this, without actually writing any SQL code at all. How could I achieve this?

Comment: The short answer is, if you need them as instances of the class then you're doing it right, if you just want "values" and don't actually need to "act" on the instances then using raw SQL is going to be much faster.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore I just need two fields of the Object so I am not actually interested in the object itself. Raw SQL is the solution for this, but it's quite a long query and the maintainability of such a query is lower than the way I am trying to do it. Isn't there a way to do this without writing raw SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at using [criteria and projections](http://grails.asia/grails-criteria-projections-examples). In your case, the query be something like the following:

```
def temperatures = Temperature.createCriteria().list(max: limit, offset: offset) {
    ...
    projections {
        property "x"
        property "y"
    }
}
```

Your two-way join makes it a little more tricky and you may have to use TripDevice instead of Temperature.